# In python curly braces with numbers from range() inside

Tags: python, string

How would I get this output?

```
'[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {6} {7} {8} {9}]'
```

I have tried this

```
string_val ='{{{}}} '.format(range(10))
```

But it gives

```
'{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]} '
```

Comment: `print('[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {6} {7} {8} {9}]')` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to format *each individual number*, then put that result into another formatting operation to add the square brackets:

```
'[{}]'.format(' '.join(['{{{}}}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

or perhaps more readable as we don't have to escape the curly braces:

```
'[{}]'.format(' '.join(['{%d}' % i for i in range(10)]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> ['{{{}}}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]
['{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}']
>>> '[{}]'.format(' '.join(['{{{}}}'.format(i) for i in range(10)]))
'[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}]'
>>> '[{}]'.format(' '.join(['{%d}' % i for i in range(10)]))
'[{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9}]'
```